# is the following new overload leaking memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading, new-operator

I have encountered the following code:

```
    class a {
    public:

        void *  operator new(size_t l, int nb);
        double  values;
    };
void *a::operator new (size_t l,int n)
{
    return new char[l+ (n>1 ? n - 1 : 0)*sizeof(double)];
}
```

From what I get it is then used to have an array like structure that start at "values":

```
double* Val = &(p->a->values) + fColumnNumber;
```

My question is :
is there a memory leak? I am very new to overloading new operator, but I'm pretty sure that the memory allocated is not deallocated properly. Also does that mean I can never create a "a" class on the stack?

thanks

Comment: The code you show doesn’t deallocate memory at all. Show this code, otherwise we cannot say whether memory is leaked. I don’t see an a priori reason to suspect memory is leaked, unless `operator delete` is really missing.

Comment: it *is* missing, that's all i have

Comment: Yes, you'll need to delete anyway, overloaded operator or not. What made you think overloading `new` would somehow work differently?

Comment: Ah, that makes the question more interesting.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Why does it make the question more interesting? It's now deteriorated into a simple missing destructor problem, that's all.

Comment: @MrLister It’s more interesting since I don’t know the answer: I don’t know whether the default `::operator delete` will be able to deallocate the correct amount of memory for this custom allocator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it technically produces UB as it is, though it's a form of UB that will probably never cause a visible side effect (it's using `new []`, but I believe that'll get matched up with `delete` -- but for `char`, this usually won't cause a visible problem).

IMO, it's almost worse that it's using a new expression to allocate what should really be raw bytes instead of objects. If I were doing it, I'd write it like:

```
void *a::operator new (size_t l,int n)
{
    return ::operator new(l+ (n>1 ? n - 1 : 0)*sizeof(double));
}
```

You'd match that up with:

```
void a::operator delete(void *block)
{
    ::operator delete(block);
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's UB that doesn't hurt anyone *and* a good alternative.

Comment: @lezebulon: Primarily that if you have an `operator new`, you should have a matching `operator delete`, if only to make it obvious that what you have is correct, and you haven't forgotten something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I was worried about was that only sizeof(a) bytes would be released when calling delete. I'm still not so sure why all the allocated memory will be freed

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the default `operator delete` called on an `a *` wouldn't be able to correctly deallocate the memory allocated by this custom `operator new`. The best way to check would be to actually write some code and find out, although rather than rob05c's technique I'd probably run it in a profiler such as valgrind. I assume the questioner sees a memory leak happening and suspects this as the cause, so writing a test case around this operator seems like a worthwhile endeavour.

Obviously it will leak if nobody gets around to actually deleting it afterwards...

I'd question the necessity of overriding `new` for this kind of functionality, but I also assume this was somebody else's code.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to find out. Write a loop that constructs and deconstructs lots of *a*'s, and watch your memory usage. It'll go up pretty fast if it's leaking.

Comment: That tells you almost nothing since the standard doesn’t specify how implementations track memory.

Answer (score 0):

Its fine as it is, but you'd need to use `delete[]`, not `delete`, from the code that uses this class as it allocates an array. Note that the user wouldn't get any hints that they need to do this - so overloading a delete operator for them would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can definitely create Class "a" on the stack.
2. There are 4 (actually more but will stick with the basics) new & delete method signatures you should know.

   ```
   void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);
   void* operator new[] (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc);
   void operator delete (void* ptr) throw ();
   void operator delete[] (void* ptr) throw ();
   ```

   You are allocating an array within the "operator new" method which should be done in the "operator new[]" method.  This will get rid of your nasty check. Write both, "operator new" and "operator new[]"
3. Don't forget you want to give the caller an object of type "a" ( `a myA = new a`) so make sure you return "a" not char*, therefore you need to also be casting.
4. You need to write the corresponding delete[] and delete methods.
5. To answer your question, I believe it does leak memory. The new signature you've provided is called the "placement new".  This allows you to allocate a new pointer without allocating memory but to give it a location to point to. Example: If you needed a pointer to a specific point in memory.

   ```
   long z = 0x0F9877F80078;
   a myA = new (z) a[5];  // 5 pointers that point to 0x0F9877F80078
   ```

By definition the placement-new operator is not supposed to allocate memory and since you have you make be leaking. Get rid of your second argument, which you can do now since you have 2 versions of operator new and you're good to go.  Don't forget to return an object "a".

Check out IBM's Info Center:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr318.htm

And the reference or references, cpluplus.com:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new